# How to configure embedded glassfish 3.1 to use an alternative port for JNDI to 3700

Tags: jndi, glassfish-3

I have a test that is successfully using embedded glassfish to test the deployment of a JCA.

However there is conflict with the running version of GlassFish 2.1 which is already using port 3700.

How can the embedded GlassFish object be configured to use an alternative port for the naming service? Ideally this could be configured from within the test.

This is the current test code,

```
    GlassFishRuntime gfRuntime = GlassFishRuntime.bootstrap();
    GlassFish glassfish = gfRuntime.newGlassFish();
    glassfish.start();

    deployJca(glassfish);

    // Do tests on object acquired from JNDI.

    glassfish.stop();
    gfRuntime.shutdown();
```

The exception is,

```
Caused by: org.omg.CORBA.COMM_FAILURE: SEVERE: IOP00410016: Unable to create IIOP listener on the specified host all interfaces and port 3,700  vmcid: OMG  minor code: 16  completed: No
Caused by: java.net.BindException: Address already in use: bind
```

Comment: It will be easier to assist with this if you include the complete ST... not just the 'Caused' lines.

Comment: It is a question about how to configure embedded GlassFish. The complete stack trace would obscure the point of the question so I won't be including it.

Answer (score 2):

The [javadoc for GlassFishRutime.newGlassFish(GlassFishProperties)](http://embedded-glassfish.java.net/nonav/apidocs/org/glassfish/embeddable/GlassFishRuntime.html#newGlassFish%28org.glassfish.embeddable.GlassFishProperties%29) and the [javadoc for GlassFishRuntime.bootstrap(BootstrapProperties)](http://embedded-glassfish.java.net/nonav/apidocs/org/glassfish/embeddable/GlassFishRuntime.html#bootstrap%28org.glassfish.embeddable.BootstrapProperties%29) are a bit wanting for detail...

There is a '--domainproperties' option described on [the asadmin create-domain reference page](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E18930_01/html/821-2433/create-domain-1.html#create-domain-1). One of the properties that you can set is called 'orb.listener.port'... That may be useful in resolving this.  I also noticed that the domain.xml file leverages system properties for port definitions (open the domain.xml file and search for 'IIOP_LISTENER_PORT').  I would guess that one of these two strings will be the key for a BootstrapProperties or GlassFishProperties property that will do what you want.

Comment: Thanks. '--portbase' looks promising.

Answer (score 1):

I got following solution (and some helpful methods):

```
public synchronized CommandResult runCommand(String command, String... parameters)
throws GlassFishException {   
  CommandRunner runner = this.gfInstance.getCommandRunner();
  CommandResult result = runner.run(command, parameters);
  checkCommandResult(command, result);
  return result;
}
private void checkCommandResult(String cmd, CommandResult result) {
  LOG.info("Command: {}\n  Result.status:\n  {}\n  Result.out:\n  {}\n  Result.failCause:\n  {}\n", 
  new Object[] {cmd, result.getExitStatus(), result.getOutput(), result.getFailureCause()});
  if (result.getExitStatus().ordinal() != 0) {
    throw new IllegalStateException("Command '" + cmd + "' was unsuccessful: " 
    + result.getOutput(),
    result.getFailureCause());
}
```

Then I can call nearly anything just like with asadmin command:
Example:

```
runCommand("list", "configs.config.server-config.iiop-service.iiop-listener");
```

produces in log:

```
  Result.status:
  SUCCESS
  Result.out:
  PlainTextActionReporterSUCCESSDescription: list AdminCommandnull
    configs.config.server-config.iiop-service.iiop-listener.SSL
    configs.config.server-config.iiop-service.iiop-listener.SSL_MUTUALAUTH
    configs.config.server-config.iiop-service.iiop-listener.orb-listener-1

  Result.failCause:
  null
```

And then you look into domain.xml again and set whatever you want:
http://embedded-glassfish.java.net/domain.xml
For example in my EGF initialization I call this before deploy and after instance startup:

```
runCommand("set", 
 "configs.config.server-config.iiop-service.iiop-listener.orb-listener-1.port=" + 50000);
runCommand("set", 
 "configs.config.server-config.iiop-service.iiop-listener.SSL.port=" + 50001);
runCommand("set", 
 "configs.config.server-config.iiop-service.iiop-listener.SSL_MUTUALAUTH.port=" + 50002);
```

Comment: Here is a good full example when using Arquillian: https://community.jboss.org/thread/230930